# How to add a field to the document which is created before?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store some details entered in **Dialogflow console** into Firestore database,

I have this following code:

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    let action = request.body.result.action;

    var Name = request.body.result.parameters.Name;

    let params = request.body.result.parameters;

    var Answer1 = request.body.result.parameters.Answer1;

    let query = request.body.result.resolvedQuery;

    const parameters = request.body.result.parameters;

    const inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts;

    console.log("Parameters is" + params);
    console.log("Answer1 is " + Answer1);
    console.log("Helllo");
    console.log("action is " + action);

    if (action == "save.name") {
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(Name)
        .set({
          name: Name,
          answer: ""
        })
        .then(ref => {
          var doc = admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(Name)
            .get();
          console.log("Added new user");
          console.log("Name is " + Name);
          console.log("ref id is:" + ref.id);
        });
    }
    //const ref = this.Name;
    if (action == "save.answer1") {
      //   var Name = this.request.body.result.parameters.Name;
      console.log("name in second if", Name);
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(doc)
        .update({
          answer: Answer1
        })
        .then(ref => {
          console.log("Added new user");
          console.log("Name is " + Name);
          console.log("ref id is:" + ref.id);
        });
    }
  }
);
```

This code successfully adds the name into the database, then quits out of code and again re-enters to save Answer1, So I don't know how to refer the document where the name is added, If I hard code the 'Name' previously entered by the user, then it adds the answer1 under the same document

example:

```
if (action == "save.answer1") {
       admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc("ABC")
        .update({
          answer: Answer1
        })
```

I have here hard-coded the name of the document as **ABC** so it adds answer1 under the document, How to avoid hard-coding the name?

I need to get the DocumentId of the document where Name is stored, So that I can add Answer1,

expected Output is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - *don't* try to find a query that finds the "last document added". I don't know if it exists, but it will do the wrong thing if you have two different users in different sessions add documents and then try to update them. This is a race condition, and it is very bad.

Instead, what you can do is save the document identifier (the name in your case) in a parameter in a Dialogflow [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). Then, the next time your webhook is called, you can retrieve the parameter from that context and use that in the `.doc()` reference.

You don't show how you're sending messages back to Dialogflow, but it looks like you might be using the Dialogflow V1 JSON. If so, you'd set the contexts back in the response under the `contextOut` attribute. This will be an array of contexts you want to set. So this portion of the JSON fragment might look something like:

```
  "contextOut": [
    {
      "name": "doc_name",
      "lifespan": 5,
      "parameters": {
        "name": Name
      }
    }
  ]
```

When handling the "save.answer1" action, you would go through the incoming contexts to find the correct context and use this name in your update. So that segment might look something like this:

```
if (action == "save.answer1") {
  var Name;
  for( var co=0; inputContexts && co<inputContexts.length && !Name; co++ ){
    var context = inputContexts[co];
    if( context.name == 'doc_name' ){
      Name = context.parameters.name;
    }
  }
  console.log("name in second if", Name);
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(Name)
    .update({
      answer: Answer1
    })
    .then(ref => {
      console.log("Updated user");
      console.log("Name is " + Name);
      console.log("ref id is:" + ref.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code worked and successfully adds the `answer1` to the document, Will this code also works for adding Many more fields to the same document?

Comment: The `if( context.name == 'doc_name' )` portion loads the name of the document that you saved in the context. I'm not sure what you're saving there. If you're continuing to have problems, creating a new StackOverflow question might be best.

Comment: I am getting errors while I try to add more fields to the database, I updated the  `if( context.name == 'doc_name' )` each time after updating a field but still it throws the `Argument "documentPath" is not a valid ResourcePath. Path must be a non-empty string.`  error.

Comment: Please create a new question and show exactly what you're doing and what errors you're getting.

Comment: I have created one explaining all the issues, please refer this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396250/cannot-able-to-add-multiple-fields-to-a-document-by-saving-the-document-name-in